# display two categories in post per page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have this code to display only one category but I want to display category 16 and category 40. So only when the users needs to select category 16 and cat 40 then this  will be display on the page:

```
    <?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 16 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
  setup_postdata( $post ); 
  ?>
    <div class="categoriesStyle"><?php exclude_post_categories("40"); ?></div>
     <div class="first"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
     <div class="paddingSpace"></div>
    <div class="contentText"><span style="color: #000"><?php echo intro_text(150); ?></span></div>
    <hr class="style-two">
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include more than one category you can use `cat` parameter instead of `category`

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset'=> 0, 'cat' => '16, 40' );
```

Or cat__in, that accept an array of category ids

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset'=> 0, 'cat__in' => array(16, 40) );
```

Be carefull about `offset` parameter that overrides $paged parameter (that you don't actually use in the present code, but can help), WP_Query class reference at [Pagination Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) part,  says:

> offset (int) - number of post to displace or pass over. Warning: Setting the offset parameter overrides/ignores the paged parameter and breaks pagination (Click here for a workaround). The 'offset' parameter is ignored when 'posts_per_page'=>-1 (show all posts) is used.

Hope its helps!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution: I did this: Where main article is the other category. Category 14 is one category and the other category is main article (I didnt put the ID, rather I put the category name and it works!

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 14, 'category_name' => 'Main article' );
```